# linq query to filter datatable with another datatable

Tags: linq

I have datatable with like 10,000 records with one of column st_ID, i want to filter is datatable based on another datatable with one of column bt_ID.

i want this solution in linq only

thanks

Comment: Now you know what you want, you might go on doing it. Come back if you get stuck anywhere, and show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Too vague, is there any foreign key relationship between the two?

In any case, you can use `Join` syntax
example:

```
from t1 in context.Table1
join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.st_ID equals t2.bt_ID
select............
```

If you have proper FK relationship, you should be able to query directly using properties.